# Why is unittest coverage disabled for Python 3.8.3?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, code-coverage, python-unittest

I have this version of Python:

```
3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

running on Windows 10 in PyCharm CE 2020.1.1. Using a very simple `unittest`:

```py
# test_simple.py

from unittest import TestCase

class Simple(TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

I can run `python -m coverage run -m unittest`, which completes and generates a `.coverage` SQLite file; and I can run the test from the IDE which produces a *Test Results* tree; but *Run* / *Run with Coverage* is grayed out with no explanation.

I have followed the (fairly scattered) PyCharm documentation to do *Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment*, *Activate Coverage View* enabled, *Show options before applying coverage to the editor* and this has not helped.

Why is coverage grayed out and how can I fix it?

Comment: As far as I know, coverage support is only available in the professional version of PyCharm.

Comment: See [the edition features](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yep, you're right. Thanks. I will accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, IDE coverage support is not available in the Community Edition of PyCharm, as can be seen in [the edition features](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

You have to run coverage on the command line as usual, as shown for example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57960457/12480730).

You could also use some wrapper that creates and opens a HTML report. An example for such a wrapper that uses pytest with coverage can be found in [this blog post](http://ingenuen.blogspot.com/2015/11/pytest-installation-and-integration.html). Here is the script used in that blog (note that I changed the coverage path to work with current versions):

```
import os
import subprocess
import webbrowser


def main():
    subprocess.call(['coverage', 'erase'])    
    subprocess.call(['coverage', 'run', '--module', 'pytest'])
    subprocess.call(['coverage', 'html'])
    webbrowser.open("file://" + os.getcwd() + "/htmlcov/index.html", new=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I suspect that most of the above is possible without the use of `subprocess`. After all, `coverage` is itself a Python module.

Comment: Yes, right - you could use `pytest.main()`, and use a `Coverage` instance for the rest, though it will not really make a difference, I guess.